# Integrating My Node js business logic with Auth0, amazon api gateway and strip payments

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, aws-api-gateway, auth0

I want to create an integrated sytem. My business logic will be on NodeJS.

I want to protect these resources and get paid by consumers for using my APIs as per my business logic.

What technology stack will be fine? I thought of using Amazon api gateway for hosting my APIs, and Auth0 for protecting these API calls.

How can I create a developer portal for my APIs?

Is this kind of infrastructure possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  API Gateway currently supports some, but not all, of your requirements.

With API Gateway, you can keep your business logic in NodeJS.  You can either run your own NodeJS server on EC2 or you can run your NodeJS logic in Lambda for a serverless solution.

API Gateway currently allows you to secure your API using Cognito user pools.  Alternatively, you can use only API keys, which aren't a strong security mechanism, but are typically used for tracking and billing API consumers.

API Gateway supports usage reports that you can use to generate bill for customers.  It doesn't currently support billing customers for you.

API Gateway does not currently support creating a developer portal for your APIs.  This is a commonly requested feature and we will probably add it at some point in the future.  You would have to build/host your own developer portal for now.